# Mismatching results for singular fit with different R/lme4 versions

Tags: r, lme4, mixed-models

I am trying to match the estimate of random effects from R version 3.5.3 (lme4 1.1-18-1) to R version 4.1.1 (lme4 1.1-27.1). However, there is a small difference of random effects between these two versions when there is singular fit. I'm fine with singularity warnings, but it is puzzling that different versions of R/lme4 produce slightly different results.

The following scripts are from R version 3.5.3 (lme4 1.1-18-1) and R version 4.1.1 (lme4 1.1-27.1) with the dataset Arabidopsis from lme4.

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.5.3 (2019-03-11)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19042)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] minqa_1.2.4     MASS_7.3-51.1   compiler_3.5.3  Matrix_1.2-15  
 [5] tools_3.5.3     Rcpp_1.0.1      splines_3.5.3   nlme_3.1-137   
 [9] grid_3.5.3      nloptr_1.2.1    lme4_1.1-18-1   lattice_0.20-38
> library(lme4)
Loading required package: Matrix
> options(digits = 15)
> ##########
> #Example1#
> ##########
> fit1 <- lmer(total.fruits~(1|reg)+(1|reg:popu),data=Arabidopsis,control=lmerControl(optimizer="bobyqa"))
> VarCorr(fit1)
 Groups   Name        Std.Dev.       
 reg:popu (Intercept)  7.744768797534
 reg      (Intercept) 10.629179104291
 Residual             39.028818969641
> ##########
> #Example2#
> ##########
> fit2 <- lmer(total.fruits~(1|reg)+(1|reg:popu)+(1|reg:popu:amd)+(1|reg:popu:amd:status),data=Arabidopsis,control=lmerControl(optimizer="bobyqa"))
> fit2@theta
[1] 0.150979711638631 0.000000000000000 0.189968995915902
[4] 0.260818869156072
> VarCorr(fit2)
 Groups              Name        Std.Dev.       
 reg:popu:amd:status (Intercept)  5.841181759473
 reg:popu:amd        (Intercept)  0.000000000000
 reg:popu            (Intercept)  7.349619506926
 reg                 (Intercept) 10.090696322743
 Residual                        38.688521100461
> ##########
> #Example3#
> ##########
> devfun353 <- lmer(total.fruits~(1|reg)+(1|reg:popu)+(1|reg:popu:amd)+(1|reg:popu:amd:status),data=Arabidopsis,control=lmerControl(optimizer="bobyqa"),devFunOnly = T)
> save.image('myEnvironment353.Rdata')
```

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.1.1 (2021-08-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19042)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] minqa_1.2.4        MASS_7.3-54        compiler_4.1.1     minque_2.0.0       Matrix_1.3-4      
 [6] tools_4.1.1        Rcpp_1.0.7         tinytex_0.34       splines_4.1.1      nlme_3.1-152      
[11] grid_4.1.1         xfun_0.27          nloptr_1.2.2.2     boot_1.3-28        lme4_1.1-27.1     
[16] ADDutil_2.2.1.9005 lattice_0.20-44   
> library(lme4)
Loading required package: Matrix
Warning message:
package ‘lme4’ was built under R version 4.1.2 
> options(digits = 15)
> ##########
> #Example1#
> ##########
> fit1 <- lmer(total.fruits~(1|reg)+(1|reg:popu),data=Arabidopsis,control=lmerControl(optimizer="bobyqa"))
> VarCorr(fit1)
 Groups   Name        Std.Dev.       
 reg:popu (Intercept)  7.744768797534
 reg      (Intercept) 10.629179104291
 Residual             39.028818969641
> ##########
> #Example2#
> ##########
> fit2 <- lmer(total.fruits~(1|reg)+(1|reg:popu)+(1|reg:popu:amd)+(1|reg:popu:amd:status),data=Arabidopsis,control=lmerControl(optimizer="bobyqa"))
boundary (singular) fit: see ?isSingular
> fit2@theta
[1] 0.150979743348540 0.000000000000000 0.189969036985684 0.260818797487214
> VarCorr(fit2)
 Groups              Name        Std.Dev.       
 reg:popu:amd:status (Intercept)  5.841182965248
 reg:popu:amd        (Intercept)  0.000000000000
 reg:popu            (Intercept)  7.349621069388
 reg                 (Intercept) 10.090693513643
 Residual                        38.688520961140
> ##########
> #Example3#
> ##########
> devfun411 <- lmer(total.fruits~(1|reg)+(1|reg:popu)+(1|reg:popu:amd)+(1|reg:popu:amd:status),data=Arabidopsis,control=lmerControl(optimizer="bobyqa"),devFunOnly = T)
> load('myEnvironment353.Rdata')
> devfun353 <- lme4:::mkdevfun(environment(devfun353))
> minqa::bobyqa(c(1,1,1,1),devfun353,0,control = list(iprint=2))
npt = 6 , n =  4 
rhobeg =  0.2 , rhoend =  2e-07 
start par. =  1 1 1 1 fn =  6443.44054431489 
rho:    0.020 eval:  11 fn:      6393.61 par: 0.00000 0.621363 0.744867 0.823498 
rho:   0.0020 eval:  38 fn:      6361.97 par:0.156855  0.00000 0.190090 0.234676 
rho:  0.00020 eval:  49 fn:      6361.94 par:0.150719  0.00000 0.190593 0.249106 
rho:  2.0e-05 eval:  67 fn:      6361.94 par:0.150988  0.00000 0.189943 0.260821 
rho:  2.0e-06 eval:  74 fn:      6361.94 par:0.150980  0.00000 0.189965 0.260811 
rho:  2.0e-07 eval:  82 fn:      6361.94 par:0.150980  0.00000 0.189969 0.260819 
At return
eval:  90 fn:      6361.9381 par: 0.150980  0.00000 0.189969 0.260819
parameter estimates: 0.150979722854965, 0, 0.189968942342717, 0.260818725554898 
objective: 6361.93810274656 
number of function evaluations: 90 
> minqa::bobyqa(c(1,1,1,1),devfun411,0,control = list(iprint=2))
npt = 6 , n =  4 
rhobeg =  0.2 , rhoend =  2e-07 
start par. =  1 1 1 1 fn =  6443.44054431489 
rho:    0.020 eval:  11 fn:      6393.61 par: 0.00000 0.621363 0.744867 0.823498 
rho:   0.0020 eval:  38 fn:      6361.97 par:0.156855  0.00000 0.190090 0.234676 
rho:  0.00020 eval:  49 fn:      6361.94 par:0.150719  0.00000 0.190593 0.249106 
rho:  2.0e-05 eval:  67 fn:      6361.94 par:0.150988  0.00000 0.189943 0.260821 
rho:  2.0e-06 eval:  74 fn:      6361.94 par:0.150980  0.00000 0.189965 0.260811 
rho:  2.0e-07 eval:  82 fn:      6361.94 par:0.150980  0.00000 0.189969 0.260819 
At return
eval:  90 fn:      6361.9381 par: 0.150980  0.00000 0.189969 0.260819
parameter estimates: 0.150979722854965, 0, 0.189968942342717, 0.260818725554898 
objective: 6361.93810274656 
number of function evaluations: 90
```

When the model is simpler, there is no singularity warning and the results match. (See example 1 in both scripts) When model is relatively complex, there is singularity warning and the results are slightly off (See example 2 in both scripts). The difference is <1e-5 in this case but I have observed <1e-4 before. Can anyone shed some lights on why the results are slightly different? and is it even possible to match the results to at least 1e-8?

Not sure if this is useful but I also extract devfun from 3.5.3 and run it in 4.1.1. The results match. (see example 3) In addition, when I read iteration history from BOBYQA, the $\theta$ of the term that leads to singularity warning oscillates between 0 and small numbers (around 1e-7 to 1e-9).

[This post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/392302/singular-fit-in-lmer-despite-no-high-correlations-of-random-effects) discusses similar topics. It also shows the singularity warning leads to slightly different estimate. There is no obvious change in [LME4 NEWS](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lme4/news.html) that cause the difference. [This FAQ](https://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.html#singular-models-random-effect-variances-estimated-as-zero-or-correlations-estimated-as---1) and [?isSingular](https://rdrr.io/cran/lme4/man/isSingular.html) give great explanation on singularity warning but does not address the issue of mismatching directly.

TL;DR: Sometimes when there is singularity warning (I am ok with), the random effects are slightly different under different R/lme4 versions. Why is this happening and how to address it?

Comment: I notice you accepted and then un-accepted. If you'd like to comment I can try to improve my answer (although I don't know that I'll be able to offer a fix in the near future)

Comment: Hi Ben, thank you for your elaborated answer! The reason that I un-accepted the answer is because the mismatch is between lme4 version 1.1-18-1 and 1.1-27.1. Therefore, the change in construction of interacting factors should not be the main reason of the mismatch since it is a change in 1.1.28. Do you mind to modify your answer to make it a bit more rigorous? I really appreciate your answer and it is really informative. Thanks you!

Comment: Based on your answer, it seems like the difference is more to do with R version changes. I accept your answer since it is informative and hopefully it can give others some idea on why the mismatch could arose.

Comment: Oh, I missed that. I will try this under Windows (I've set up a Windows VM) and see if I can see any differences (although I doubt it), which leads me to believe that it is indeed a difference somewhere else in the stack (compiler, other package versions, R version). I don't think I have the time/energy patience to do all the necessary archaeology there ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a hard problem to solve in general, and even a fairly hard problem to solve in specific cases.

I **think** the difference arose between version 1.1.27.1 and 1.1.28, probably from this NEWS item:

> construction of interacting factors (e.g. when f1:f2 or f1/f2 occur in random effects terms) is now more efficient for partially crossed designs (doesn't try to create all combinations of f1 and f2) (GH #635 and #636)

My guess is that this changes the ordering of the components in the Z matrix, which in turn means that results of various linear algebra operations are not identical (e.g. floating point arithmetic is **not associative**, so while binary addition is commutative (`a + b == b + a`), left-to-right evaluation of a sum may not be the same as right-to-left evaluation (`(a+b) + c != a + (b+c)`) ...)

My attempt at reproducing the problem uses the same version of R ("under development 2022-02-25 r81818") and compares only `lme4` package versions 1.18.1 with 1.1.28.9000 (development); any upstream packages such as `Rcpp`, `RcppEigen`, `Matrix` use the same versions. (I had to backport a few changes from the development version of `lme4` to 1.1.18.1 to get it to install under the most recent version of R, but I don't think any of those modifications would affect numerical results.)

I did the comparison by installing different versions of the `lme4` package before running the code in a fresh R session. My results differed between versions 1.1.18.1 and 1.1.28 less than yours did (both fits were singular, and the relative differences in the `theta` estimates were of the order of 2e-7 — still greater than your desired 1e-8 tolerance but much smaller than 1e-4 ...)

The results from 1.1.18.1 and 1.1.27.1 were identical.

- Q1: Why are your results more different between versions than mine?

  - in general/anecdotally, numerical results on Windows are slightly more unstable/differ more from other platforms
  - there are more differences between your two test platforms than among mine: R version, upstream packages (`Matrix`/`Rcpp`/`RcppEigen`/`minqa`), possibly the compiler versions and settings used to build everything [all of which could make a difference]
- Q2: how should one deal with this kind of problem?

  - as a minor frame challenge, why (other than not understanding what's going on, which is a perfectly legitimate reason to be concerned) does this worry you? The differences in the results are *way* smaller than the magnitude of statistical uncertainty, and differences this large are also likely to occur across different platforms (OS/compiler version/etc.) even for otherwise identical environments (versions of R, `lme4`, and other packages).
  - you could revert to version 1.1.27.1 for now ...
  - I do take the differences between 1.1.27.1 as a bug, of sorts — at the very least it's an undocumented change in the package. If it were sufficiently high-priority I could investigate the code changes described above and see if there is a way to fix the problems they addressed without breaking backward compatibility (in theory this should be possible, but it could be annoyingly difficult ...)

---

```r
## R CMD INSTALL ~/R/misc/lme4
library(lme4)
packageVersion("lme4")
## 1.1.18.1
fit2 <- lmer(total.fruits~(1|reg)+(1|reg:popu)+(1|reg:popu:amd)+(1|reg:popu:amd:status),data=Arabidopsis,control=lmerControl(optimizer="bobyqa"))
dput(getME(fit2, "theta"))
t1 <- c(`reg:popu:amd:status.(Intercept)` = 0.150979711638631, `reg:popu:amd.(Intercept)` = 0,
`reg:popu.(Intercept)` = 0.189968995915902, `reg.(Intercept)` = 0.260818869156072
)
```

Run under 1.1.28.9000 (fresh R session, re-run package-loading/`lmer` code above)

```r
## R CMD INSTALL ~/R/pkgs/lme4git/lme4
packageVersion("lme4")
## [1] ‘1.1.28.9000’
dput(getME(fit2, "theta"))
t2 <- c(`reg:popu:amd:status.(Intercept)` = 0.15097974334854, `reg:popu:amd.(Intercept)` = 0,
`reg:popu.(Intercept)` = 0.189969036985684, `reg.(Intercept)` = 0.260818797487214
)

(t1-t2)/((t1+t2)/2)
## reg:popu:amd:status.(Intercept)        reg:popu:amd.(Intercept)
##                   -2.100276e-07                             NaN
##            reg:popu.(Intercept)                 reg.(Intercept)
##                  -2.161920e-07                    2.747841e-07
```

The second element is `NaN` because both versions give singular fits (0/0 == NaN).

Run under 1.1.27.1 (fresh R session, re-run package-loading/`lmer` code above)

```r
## remotes::install_version("lme4", "1.1-27.1")

t3 <- c(`reg:popu:amd:status.(Intercept)` = 0.150979711638631, `reg:popu:amd.(Intercept)` = 0,
`reg:popu.(Intercept)` = 0.189968995915902, `reg.(Intercept)` = 0.260818869156072)

identical(t1, t3) ## TRUE
```