# R package lme4: modeling results changed recently

Tags: r, lme4, mixed-models

I've been using lme4 in R for linear mixed-effects modeling for a couple of years. I have some older scripts and data, and now I need to check a few output numbers. However, when I run the analysis on the same data by using exactly the same scripts, the output numbers are all different from those I got several months ago. Sometimes it's just a slight difference, but sometimes it's a critical one. How is that possible? Could it be that the script developers made some changes in underlying math? Is there a way to get back to previous versions of calculations?

Comment: On the [lme4 CRAN site](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lme4/index.html) you find a link to the [`lme4 archive`](https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/lme4/) from where you could try to install an older version matching the date of your script using e.g.  `install.packages('https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/lme4/lme4_1.1-23.tar.gz', repo=NULL, type="source")`.

Comment: I'm reminded of this recent Q&A : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71340249/mismatching-results-for-singular-fit-with-different-r-lme4-versions/71344354#71344354 . But your question would benefit by at least showing the models and results for each version and your system details.